# Would a SSD help in the generation speed of ipa files?

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation, ipa, solid-state-drive

I'm running into ipa generation times of 15-20 mins.. and I'd love to cut it at least by half.

I don't have currently an SSD, so, I was wondering, since I got tons of little files, assets mostly, would it improve the compilation time if I run everything on an SSD?.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your machine specs? SSD is unlikely to help, since the majority of the time is spent compiling, not creating or reading file. I have an old MacBook with a 2.2GHz C2D CPU and 4GB RAM that takes 20+ minutes, but my work machine with 8GB RAM and a 2.5GHz Quad Core i7 takes 3. Both run 5400 RPM HDDs, too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give [tmpfs](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~vcss544/tmpfs.pdf) a try if all your intermediate files can be held in memory.

And of course the SSD can improve the performance over the hard disks.

Comment: But that would help only if the process is actually I/O intensive, maybe this is mostly CPU intensive, that's what I don't know.